# Populate table view with jsonresult after send httpost parameter to stored procedure

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

```
public class spSeguimientoCred_Result 
{ 
    public string DNI { get; set; }
    public string APELLIDO_PATERNO { get; set; }
    public string APELLIDO_MATERNO { get; set; }
    public string NOMBRES_DEL_NIÑO { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> FECHA_DE_NACIMIENTO { get; set; }
    public string EDAD { get; set; }
    public string TIPO_DE_SEGURO { get; set; }
    public string PROGRAMAS_SOCIALES { get; set; }
    public string CENTRO_POBLADO { get; set; }
    public string DIRECCION { get; set; }
    public string Establecimiento_Ultimo_Control { get; set; }
    public string UltimoControlCred { get; set; }
    public string ProximoControlCred { get; set; }
    public  string Establecimiento { get; set; }

}
```

This is my model.

```
public JsonResult GetSeguimientoP(string Establecimiento)
    {
        var cadena = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Cnn"].ConnectionString;
        List<spSeguimientoCred_Result> lista = new List<spSeguimientoCred_Result>();
        using (var cn = new SqlConnection(cadena))
        {
            try
            {
                cn.Open();
                using (var cmd = cn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "spSeguimientoCred";
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@textobuscar2", Establecimiento);
                    var drd = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    while (drd.Read())
                    {
                        var atenciones = new spSeguimientoCred_Result
                        {
                            DNI = drd.GetString(drd.GetOrdinal("DNI")),
                            APELLIDO_PATERNO = drd.GetString(drd.GetOrdinal("APELLIDO PATERNO")),
                            APELLIDO_MATERNO = drd.GetString(drd.GetOrdinal("APELLIDO MATERNO")),
                            NOMBRES_DEL_NIÑO = drd.GetString(drd.GetOrdinal("NOMBRES DEL NIÑO")),
                            FECHA_DE_NACIMIENTO = drd.GetDateTime(drd.GetOrdinal("FECHA DE NACIMIENTO")),
                            EDAD = drd.GetString(drd.GetOrdinal("EDAD")),
                            TIPO_DE_SEGURO = drd.GetString(drd.GetOrdinal("TIPO DE SEGURO")),
                            PROGRAMAS_SOCIALES = drd.GetString(drd.GetOrdinal("PROGRAMA SOCIAL")),
                            CENTRO_POBLADO = drd.GetString(drd.GetOrdinal("NOMBRE DE CENTRO POBLADO")),
                            Establecimiento_Ultimo_Control = drd.GetString(drd.GetOrdinal("ESTABLECIMIENTO")),
                            UltimoControlCred = drd.GetString(drd.GetOrdinal("UltimoControlCred")),
                            ProximoControlCred = drd.GetString(drd.GetOrdinal("ProximoControlCred"))
                        };
                        lista.Add(atenciones);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Open) cn.Close();
            }
        }

        return Json(lista.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

This is my `jsonresult` method in the controller. This method can return all the data I need, the problem is when I tried to show it in my table. The data show as json `[{"DNI": 546164...}]`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var tr;
    $("#btnSeguimiento").on("click", function (eve) {
        eve.preventDefault();
        
        $('#tableSeguimiento tbody').empty();
        var Establecimiento = $("#Establecimiento").val();

        if (Establecimiento == null) {
            document.alert("Ingrese Establecimiento");
            return;
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetSeguimientoP", "Seguimiento")',
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: { 'Establecimiento': Establecimiento },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {

                $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                    var row = "";
                    row += "<tr><td>" + item.ClientNo
                        + "</td><td>" + item.ClientName
                        + "</td></tr>";
                    $('#tblClients tbody').append(row);
                })
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("Error");
            }
        })
    });
});
```

This is how I tried to show it in the table. Passing the `Establecimiento` parameter to my method.

Comment: So, what happens when you run it?  We get that it isn't doing what you want, but is it failing to compile? Throwing an error? Showing the wrong data? Showing part of the data?  Showing no data?

Comment: Do you know if the AJAX is being called? Do you know for sure that the call is returning any data?

Comment: Okay, I just saw where you said the data displayed in your table as JSON.  It looks to me as if the Ajax call you posted is NOT the one you're using, because the code you posted is not going to display anything but empty rows.  So, please correct your post to include the code you are ACTUALLY using.

Comment: Ann L. Yes is returning my data, but i want to display in the table. The ajax and the parameter i send works.

Comment: The page reloads and show the data and json format. I can't figure it out how to prevent that, and just fill my table.

Comment: Can you post sample JSON data please.

Comment: Is the `GetSeguimientoP` the controller method, or something called by the controller? It looks to me like the controller is sending back an `ActionResult` that is calling for the entire page to be reloaded. A `JsonResult` is not supposed to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I have taken a guess at the JSON for now. If you can supply sample JSON we can refine the solution.

```js
let sampleJSON = {
  clients: [{
      ClientNo: 1,
      ClientName: 'test'
    },
    {
      ClientNo: 2,
      ClientName: 'test2'
    }
  ]
};



const processData = (data) => {
  let row = "";
  console.log(data.clients);
  data.clients.forEach(client => {    
    row += `<tr>
              <td>${client.ClientNo}</td>
              <td>${client.ClientName}</td>
            </tr>`;

  });
  console.log(row);
  $('#tblClients tbody').append(row);
};

processData(sampleJSON);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tblClients">
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```